# Remove column using list.files in R

Tags: r, subset

So, I've got the following script

```
output <- list.files(pattern = "some_files.csv", recursive = TRUE) %>%
    lapply(read_csv) %>%
    bind_rows
```

and it's works perfect find all posibble files `csvs`and making one big file, but i encountered the following problem, one `csv` file generate error: `` Error: Column `some_column` can't be converted from numeric to character ``. And I decided to remove this column from the dataset

```
output <- list.files(pattern = "some_files.csv", recursive = TRUE) %>%
    lapply(read_csv) %>%  subset(read_csv, select = -c(some_column)) %>%
    bind_rows
```

that genearte another error

```
Error in subset.default(., read_csv, select = -c(some_column)) : 
  'subset' must be logical
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
list.files(pattern = "some_files.csv", recursive = TRUE) %>%
    purrr::map_df(~{
        x <- readr::read_csv(.)
        x[setdiff(names(x), "some_column")]
})
```

Instead of `lapply` we use `map`, to avoid `bind_rows` at the end we can use `map_df` or `map_dfr`. Instead of `subset` we use `setdiff` to remove columns since `subset` would fail in case if the column is not present.

Or keeping everything in base R

```
file_names <- list.files(pattern = "some_files.csv", recursive = TRUE) 
do.call(rbind, lapply(file_names, function(x) {
    df <- read.csv(x)
    df[setdiff(names(df), "some_column")]
))
```